# Amazon RDS Maria DB "Unknown storage engine 'XtraDB'"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, xtradb

I'm using the free tier of Amazon RDS with Maria DB; all as basic configuration as it offers while I get to grips with RDS.

I'm getting the following error from the MariaDB instance when I try to use the XtraDB engine:

> [2017-03-09 09:08:42] [42000][1286] Unknown storage engine 'XtraDB'
>
> [2017-03-09 09:08:42] [HY000][1266] Using storage engine InnoDB for table 'table_1'
>
> [2017-03-09 09:08:42] completed in 346ms

Here is the example sql:

```
  CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `column_1`   VARCHAR(160) DEFAULT ''
  )
  ENGINE = XtraDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XtraDB` is a drop-in replacement for `InnoDB`, which, among other things, means that you get to keep the same syntax as you use for `InnoDB`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `column_1`   VARCHAR(160) DEFAULT ''
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

(note `ENGINE = InnoDB` instead of `ENGINE = XtraDB`).